# Android: how to make *truly* transparent activity SwipePad style?

Tags: android, android-activity, transparent

So yes, I know how to make my Activity look transparent (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android), but I want the user being able to interact with what ever screen they are (for example YouTube), like done in SwipePad. Now I can make it transparent, but the user can't do anything before exiting my activity.

I know this is possible as it's already done in SwipePad, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the thing I was looking wasn't a transparent activity - it was a system overlay. More info here: [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take a look at `FrameLayout` or `SurfaceView`.
There's a high chance `SurfaceView` is the answer.